# Customize Table to Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to create a TOC where the page number appears first.
Also I would like the page of TOC  is a 2 column page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Gubert Farnsworth}
\date{ }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\pagebreak 
\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Section}


 \section*{Unnumbered Section}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
 Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
 sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

 \pagebreak
 \section{Second Section}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
 Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
 sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please ask your two separate questions as different questions on this site. Which class are you using?

Comment: Please add a minimal example of what the LaTeX code you tried so far.

Comment: Solution could be pretty simple with package etoc. Look on the documentation on CTAN (It has multicol style for toc, maybe there is a command to be rewritten to switch position of page number and toc label).

Comment: Would u please provide an example